# GeoJson Jackson - parse JSON to Java object fails

Tags: java, jackson, geojson, json-deserialization, objectmapper

I am working on parsing a GeoJSON file into Java POJO classes.
I have found the GeoJSON Jackson library which seems to be exactly the same as I need.

https://github.com/opendatalab-de/geojson-jackson

I have a JSON like the following:

```
    {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "lfdNr": 1,
        "betriebsNummer": 33,
        "nummer": 4,
        "bezeichnung": "TERST",
        "kng": 61062323,
        "nArtCode": "A",
        "nArtB": "ACKERLAND",
        "flaeche": 4.0748
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              15.8867118536754,
              48.4004384452486
            ],
            [
              15.884483831836,
              48.3981983444393
            ],
            [
              15.8847389374202,
              48.3991957290405
            ],
            [
              15.8853143451339,
              48.3991585954555
            ],
            [
              15.8851662097189,
              48.398462039698
            ],
            ....
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I wish to use it as a FeatureCollection java object:

```
objectMapper.readValue(json, FeatureCollection.class);
```

I get the following:

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct 
    instance of `org.geojson.GeoJsonObject` 
(no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, 
have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (String)"{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"lfdNr":1,"betriebsNummer":10086722,"nummer":4,"bezeichnung":"TERST","fskennung":61062323,"nutzungsArtCode":"A","nutzungsArtBezeichnung":"ACKERLAND","flaeche":4.0748},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[15.8867118536754,48.4004384452486],[15.8829132747878,48.4002081767679],["[truncated 2362 chars]; line: 1, column: 251] 
 (through reference chain: org.geojson.FeatureCollection["features"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.geojson.Feature["geometry"])
```

I assume it is because the class Geometry a generic type is:

```
public abstract class Geometry<T> extends GeoJsonObject
```

I only operate with Polygons and Points.

Any ides how can I get it working?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can read this JSON content by

```
GeoJsonObject object = objectMapper.readValue(json, GeoJsonObject.class);
if (object instanceof FeatureCollection) {
    FeatureCollection featureCollection = (FeatureCollection) object;
    ...
}
```

Jackson will automatically recognize your JSON example as a `FeatureCollection` object,
because of the annotations on the `GeoJsonObject` class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(property = "type", use = Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({ @Type(Feature.class), ...,  @Type(FeatureCollection.class), ... })
...
public abstract class GeoJsonObject implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I've tried your suggestion and received the following: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.geojson.GeoJsonObject` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information at [Source: (String)"{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"l....},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[15.8867118536754,...],["[truncated 2362 chars]; line: 1, column: 1

Comment: @dorcsi For me it works (using jackson 2.11.3, geojson-jackson 1.14)